# Stackexchange used for phishing?

Tags: discussion, security

No so long ago I received a rather suspicious personal email related to a question I answered on SE.Economics.

> Hi Martin,
>
> I wanted some help with a question you answered on a blog about Signalling games and Intuitive Criterion. Could you be able to forward me to or give me a good tip in answering this question? Outline Spence Signalling Modelling ( I am guess using the education one) and Which equilibrium satisfies Intuitive Criterion? I am guess the separating one modelling.
>
> Thank you for taking your time to read this email and appreciate your help! [...]

I have no intention whatsoever to answer the sender, but I am still curious : do people on StackExchange have experience of this kind of emails being used for phishing purposes? Or would you think this is legit (again completely out of curiosity)?

Comment: Did the email include any links that *did not* go to the actual posts? Simply mouse-over and let your email client tell you the real target in the footer or a tooltip. If they go to the actual posts, then it is *extremely unlikely* to be phishing. If in doubt, inspect the email source.

Comment: No, not a single link in the email.

Comment: Then how would the sender ever be able to trick you into divulging your credentials?

Comment: But to add another datapoint: yes, I do occasionally have people poke me about answering their questions. For the most part I ignore those. Most of them are not in my areas of expertise even, or of such low quality that all they get from me is a close vote, rarely the reaction they hoped for.

Comment: Maybe I am not using the term "phishing" appropriately.  I thought of this mail as potentially similar to others in which the sender says something like "contact me, I need help" and eventually tries to get something out of you after having established some form of personal contact with you. I don't know if those really qualify as "phishing" though.

Comment: That's called *Being a Help Vampire*. Phishing is [invariably about stealing credentials and other sensitive information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I always find this kind of thing rather strange - why go via email when you can ask on the site and have multiple people around to answer?

I too have gotten the occasional email from an individual, asking me to answer *their* question (sometimes the question is in the email, sometimes it is a link to the question page on a Stack Exchange site).

In my experience these are benign - no phishing attempt.

Having said that - you never know... as always, when dealing with email from unknown entities, practice caution.